# React useState: Always rerenders when state is an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app where I have an array as a state. Then I have a timer that reads an array. Now I want to rerender only if there is a difference between the array I read and my state array.

But when I do as in the following code example it always rerenders. If I instead have a state with just a number, and set the same number, it will not rerender. Is there a way to achieve the same thing with an array? Or do I have to compare the arrays first, and then call setMeasData only if they are different?

A second question is why the rerenders variable is always increased by two the code sandbox? This does not happen in my real application, so that is not a big deal. Just curious.

Thanks!

```
let rerenders = 0;

function getMeas() {
  return [{ name: "Measurement 1", value: 0 }];
}

export default function App() {
  const [measData, setMeasData] = React.useState([
    { name: "Measurement 1", value: 0 }
  ]);

  rerenders++;

  console.log("Rerenders: " + rerenders);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useEffect");
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Timer triggered");
      let newMeasData = getMeas();
      // Want this to trigger rerender only if newMeasData is not the same as measData
      setMeasData(newMeasData);
    }, 10 * 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>No of rerenders: {rerenders} </h2>
      <p>
        {" "}
        {measData[0].name}: {measData[0].value}{" "}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bardeen-w0obe?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Try setting the state like this --> setMeasData([...newMeasData]);

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

That's because on every interval you're setting a new value to the `setMeasData` and you can check this by using this operation:

```
console.log(getMeas() === getMeas()) // which always logs false
```

everytime `getMeas` function is called it will return a new `instance` and in `React` when the `state` is changed we're going to have a rerender

if you want to have just something to set the `initialValue` you could do so by storing the value in a variable like below so you're instance always will be the same and you won't have extera rerenders:

```
let rerenders = 0;

const initialValue = [{ name: "Measurement 1", value: 0 }];

export default function App() {
  const [measData, setMeasData] = React.useState(initialValue);

  rerenders++;

  console.log("Rerenders: " + rerenders);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("In useEffect");
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Timer triggered");
      let newMeasData = initialValue;
      // Want this to trigger rerender only if newMeasData is not the same as measData
      setMeasData(newMeasData);
    }, 1 * 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <h2>
        No of rerenders: {rerenders} {`${initialValue === initialValue}`}{" "}
      </h2>
      <p>
        {" "}
        {measData[0].name}: {measData[0].value}{" "}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But it doesn't really solve my problem. I'm reading data periodically and the data may or may not be updated. It seems unnecessary to rerender if no data has changed. I added this to avoid rerendering when no data is updated: 
`if (JSON.stringify(newMeasData) !== JSON.stringify(measData)) { setMeasData(newMeasData); }`

Comment: That's a bit messy, there are two scenarios here, first: you can keep the reference of the value you're trying to store value as a state which in this case you're good to go and no matter how many times you set the state with that value, because the reference didn't change, react won't rerender the app, check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-brahmagupta-zebmp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Jimbo the second scenario is that you can pass the value as `prop` and use `memo` to memoize the component so no matter if the value change react would compare them internally, or you can use `useMemo` and `useCallback` in the parent component when you're setting the data so you're data only would change when need it

Answer (score 0):

regarding "A second question is why the rerenders variable is always increased by two the code sandbox?"

In development react always renders your component twice for debugging purposes, to make sure the functional component is "pure"
https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure
https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development